# How to populate multiple fields with Mongoose in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

In Mongoose's documentation, it says that I can apply population on multiple paths in a model:

```js
Story.
  find(...).
  populate('fans').
  populate('author').
  exec();
```

However, when I use Mongoose in TypeScript it look like I can no longer do that. Since the `populate` method returns a promise I get this error message when I try to chain them together:

```
Property 'populate' does not exist on type 'Promise<Document<any, any, unknown> & { _id: ObjectId; }>'.ts(2339)
```

What I'm actually wondering is how does Mongoose execute the population behind the scenes for multiple paths? When I chain them in plain JavaScript, does it use a single query to the database or does it query the database separately for each path? (I guess if the latter is true I could simple just have multiple `await` statements for all the different paths and call it a day...)